# Display PHP array variable inside Javascript code

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

I have a php variable called `$usershours` that contains an array, and I want to echo it inside Javascript code. How do I do that?

I tried This, but it didn't work:

```
$usershours = "
data.addRow([ new Date(2012,4,1),50119]).+'<br>+'.
data.addRow([ new Date(2012,4,2),242575])";

<script type="text/javascript">
document.write($arrayholder);
</script>
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
data.addRow([ new Date(2012,4,1),50119]) 
data.addRow([ new Date(2012,4,2),242575])
```

PS - I need this format because This is the format that Google charts API accept to render charts correctly.

Comment: PHP is executing on the server and sending the browser HTML and JavaScript. Where are you expecting this to take place?

Comment: wrap it in `<script>` ---- the JavaScript

Comment: $usershours doesn't have an array as a value...

Comment: @kech Is `$usershours` an array? It seems to be a string.

Comment: @databyss, this is the code, <?php 
$usershours = "data.addRow([ new Date(2012,4,1),50119]) 
data.addRow([ new Date(2012,4,2),242575]) ";
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var arrayholder = "<?php print_r($usershours);?>";
document.write(arrayholder);
</script>
Thanks!

Comment: @irrelephant,I think it's an array, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @locrizak, I tried it and it didn't work, thanks though!!

Comment: Why print_r? just use echo, or json_encode.

Comment: try this: http://codepad.org/IQSPUv7d

Comment: @databyss, empty result, thanks a lot for trying, i do really appreciate it!!

Comment: This isn't a game. `$usershours = "data.addRow([ new Date(2012,4,1),50119]) 
data.addRow([ new Date(2012,4,2),242575]) "; echo $usersHours;` is the output you asked for. You will not see anything on the screen, as the resulting JavaScript just calls a function on the `data` object. If there is more you are expecting, you need to write a different question.

Comment: @Cranio, I tried them, non of them works, thanks a lot!!, hope we will find something, I spend 4 hours with it but no luck,

Comment: @DanGrossman, correct, but I want it to be inside the javascript code. it's very tricky.

Comment: It's not tricky at all. Put that between `<script>` and `</script>` tags.

Comment: @DanGrossman, gave me empty result. javascript is hard for her to understand php code.

Comment: Stop trolling. It does exactly what you asked. JavaScript and PHP do the same thing on everyone's computers; it can't not work for you but work for us. We're talking about 2 lines of code here. Right click on your webpage in the browser and click "view source". You will see the two calls to `addRow` inside JavaScript tags, exactly as you asked.

Comment: This is ridiculous. If you want your output to be `"data.addRow([ new Date(2012,4,1),50119]) 
data.addRow([ new Date(2012,4,2),242575])`, then all the code you need is `?>data.addRow([ new Date(2012,4,1),50119]) 
data.addRow([ new Date(2012,4,2),242575])<?php`.

Comment: @DanGrossman, thanks a lot for metioning that, I didn't check the source code, thanks again! I want just to know if there's any way to display it on the webpage?

Comment: @meagar, correct, but in this case I want to use the result inside the javascript tag so I could use it to render a google chart to display some graphs.

Comment: Then wrap `<script>` tags around it: `?><script>data.addRow([ new Date(2012,4,1),50119]) 
data.addRow([ new Date(2012,4,2),242575])</script><?php`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I gather, you want this code run by javascript on the client machine:

```
data.addRow([ new Date(2012,4,1),50119]) 
data.addRow([ new Date(2012,4,2),242575])
```

Simply:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php 
$usershours = "
data.addRow([ new Date(2012,4,1),50119])
data.addRow([ new Date(2012,4,2),242575])";

echo $usershours;
?>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying, but it gaves me empty result.

Comment: Please define "empty result", because those words obviously mean something different to you than to everyone else. This code does exactly what you asked. We're not "trying" at some game; your question has been answered.

Comment: @DanGrossman, you are correct, but what I meant with my question was to display it on the webpage, because I will use the result for google chart API to display some graphs. thanks again man!

Comment: @DanGrossman Empty result mean, white page, but you will find the code in the source code.

Comment: A white page, with the `data.addRow` statements inside some JavaScript, is exactly what you asked for. You didn't ask for any text or HTML to be written.

Comment: @DanGrossman you are correct, I forgot that you can display the result inside the source code without displaying it on the webpage. sorry about that, I'm very new to php javascript, I want just to learn, and I came her because I know there are a smart people here that they could help me.

Answer (score 3):

Though messing PHP with JS is far from an optimal approach, this will keep your code a bit tidier as well.

Let's pretend your data comes from an array [fetched from a database or a file] such composed:

```
$data = array(
    array("date" => "2012-04-01", "id" => 50119),
    array("date" => "2012-04-02", "id" => 242575)
);
```

Through `json_encode($data)` you get this output:

```
[
  { date : "2012-04-01", id : 50119},
  { date : "2012-04-02", id : 242575}
]
```

Now you know how to translate your data from a PHP structure to a Javascript one, it's just a matter of writing:

```
<script>

  var serverData = <?php echo json_encode($data) ?>;

  for(var i = 0; i < serverData.length; i++)
  {

     data.addRow([ new Date( serverData[i].date ), serverData[i].id ]);

  }

</script>
```

Granted that `data.addRow()` is a function declared somewhere in you JS code.

Answer (score -1):

Simply use `var arrayholder = <?php json_encode($usershours);?>;` if `arrayholder` has to be output as **string** (and not as code)

Comment: Semicolons are not required in JavaScript as long as you avoid a few ambiguous syntax gotchas.

Comment: 1. and 2. are irrelevant and false respectively.

Comment: **@Dan Grossman:** Yeah as far as I know only expressions need that semicolon `;(...)`, `;[...]` and `;/.../`, and also `"use strict";` for some reason.

Comment: Corrected. Thanks for ponting my errors out.

Answer (score -2):

General advice: do not try to render valid JavaScript from PHP. It will eventually bite you, some alternate solutions: embedding the data in an HTML element and extracting it via JavaScript and Ajax

Having said that

```
?>
(function () {
   console.log(<?= json_encode($phpVar); ?>);
}());
<?
```

is how I do it when I'm ok with shooting myself in the foot

Comment: By bite you I mean render an unexpected error in the middle of your JavaScript, due to some configuration you can't control.

Comment: Why would you want to embed the data in an HTML element when you can just echo it out in js?

Comment: That's a pretty arbitrary rule to impose on yourself, also pretty irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @jeroen Because HTML doesn't crash the way JavaScript does on bad input.

Comment: @meager, yeah it's pretty arbitrary to want my software to work.

Comment: JavaScript crashing is no more or less damaging to your app than malformed HTML which your JavaScript depends on. If you are writing software which outputs PHP errors, it's because you're writing *bad software*, and you need to *fix it* regardless of whether the errors appear in your HTML or in your JavaScript. If you want your software to work you need to write error-free software, not try to hide the errors in HTML because "HTML doesn't crash". That is an utterly ridiculous attitude and an incredibly silly programming practice.

Comment: In HTML you can put escape sequences that prevent the DOM from being munged ( <![CDATA[]]> ). Afaik there is no equivalent cross-browser escape sequence in JavaScript.

Comment: And it's clearly my fault that I'm expected to write code that will work in environments I don't control. And it makes my software bad as a result. </sacrasm>

Comment: What you are saying is the equivalent of using a text-file instead of a database to store data just to avoid sql injection. It's not a solution; it's avoiding to deal with the real problem.

Comment: @Mythril It is 2012. You have to try pretty hard to write non-portable code, especially in an *interpreted language* like PHP. You absolutely should be writing code that will work in environments you don't control. This is a side-effect of writing *good software*. And again, being able to *escape* errors is utterly wrong-headed thinking. The problem is that you have errors. The solution is to **fix those errors**, not find new and inventive ways to ignore them.

Comment: @Meager You're saying I'm wrong because you don't like the way I do it. And as evidence you just denigrate my skill.

Comment: @meager, I have no way to fix shared hosts ancient deployments.

Comment: @Mythril The solution is to write good code and make a reasonably modern installation of PHP a requirement for running your software. Writing software to run on broken hosts is incredibly self-defeating. I haven't said anything about your skill, but I will say that worrying about only mixing PHP with your HTML because "you can put escape sequences that prevent the DOM from being munged ( `<![CDATA[]]>` )" is a *horrendous* way of designing software.

Comment: @meager so I should dump clients because good is the enemy of perfect?

Comment: No, you should just write good software. If your clients have a specific environment that you know you're going to have to deploy to, you should *still* write error-free code. There is no excuse for having to hide or suppress PHP errors. You're running code in a deterministic environment. You *can* fix your code.

Comment: @meager do you use third party libraries? Actually nevermind, you're determined to tell yourself I'm a bad coder, no amount of reasoning will bring you to understand that other people have other priorities than you and other constraints.

Comment: Good third party libraries publish their requirements. If my environment doesn't meet them, I won't use them. I have never encountered a third party library which would work, but then dump random errors into my output necessitating the sprinkling of CDATA block around my PHP, "just in case". This is not a thing I worry about, because when I *do* encounter an error, I *fix it*. I cannot invision a situation in which the correct solution to PHP errors corrupting your HTML is to wrap the errors in CDATA tags. That is a crazy way of building software.

Comment: @meager, I personally find it crazy to embed a Turing complete language as a string inside of another Turing complete language.

Comment: @Mythril That's largely irrelevant. I don't care *how* you render your JavaScript. The insane thing is thinking that you're somehow saving yourself grief by make sure PHP spews errors out into the HTML sections of your page instead of the `<script>` sections. How is your app more functional if the JavaScript doesn't "crash", but instead has no valid data to work with? When are doing to choose the "make sure it's less broken" option instead of just making sure your PHP runs cleanly?